# lightning-vertical-navigation-item font color

Tags: lightning-web-components

I just created side bar component using lightning-vertical-navigation in that I just created sub navigation items called "Employee Info" while I click this employee info it need to display another component called employee info. But I just gave the background color of this navigation item as black also the lightning-vertical-navigation-item font color also black it doesn't look good I can't even see the navigation item text.

"I need to change the lightning-vertical-navigation-item font color"

I refer the documentation but there is no reference about this...

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html)  css don't leak from your component to its children. Only if [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#site-main-content) are available you can modify the CSS of a standard component.

Indeed the `color` CSS property of a `lightning-vertical-navigation-item` is set by the `slds-nav-vertical__action` CSS class:

```css
color: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-10, var(--lwc-colorTextDefault, rgb(24, 24, 24)));
```

Since it uses a CSS custom property, you can override it, but in order to do it only in the right section, you could add a custom class to your container, then set it.
Something like:

**CSS**

```css
:host .green {
    --lwc-colorTextDefault: #00FF00;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-vertical-navigation>
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Green Section" class="green">
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Green" name="green"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Also green" name="also-green"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Black Section">
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Black" name="black"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

The output will be:
[image: Green-Vertical-Item]

If a styling hook is not available, you could build your own component starting from the [blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-navigation/#Expanded).